# How can we give custom color to keyboard in android / ios react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

custom color for keyboard in react-native
How can we give custom color to keyboard in android / ios react native

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, but you can create your own custom keyboard. [Check here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-keyboard-input)